# Why does Columns("F:F").Select select the entire sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, select

I'm using a macro to do a lot of formatting on a reoccurring document in our organization. When I run the macro, the formatting is completed but the contents are deleted... This macro code was written using Record option.

Using step through I determined the issue is coming from these commands:

```
Columns("F:F").Select 
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

DETERMINED ISSUE:
While stepping through I notice the command:

```
  Columns("F:F").Select
```

selects all the cells in the sheet. The next command deletes the sheets contents. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Possible issue why `Columns("F:F").Select ` selects all sheet but not only `F` column is that you have a row that is merged into a single cell

Comment: The macro runs a lot of formatting commands (column widths, etc). One of the commands I need to do is delete column F.

Comment: Delete the column or the content of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user simoco suggested i tested if merging all columns in a row could cause the behaviour:

```
Sub WhyIsWholSheetDeleted()
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

I merged every cell in row ten and executed the above function. It deletes every cell in the sheet.

So you have to find where your macro merges cells.

You can take a look in the code for something like:

```
 Rows("12:12").Select
 With Selection
    .MergeCells = True
 End With
```

Comment: The merged cell ended up being the issue. Thanks, Simoco and 341613!